# Extract number from Excel cell in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, numbers

I have a number of excel cells with the number and alphabetical characters inside each cell like: `+ 0.01 PD, OR, - 0.0005 PD, OR, - 0.001 PD`, ....
How can I extract just the number from the cell? Thanks

Comment: What language are you using? if python then a simple regex `\d+` will do. - if so let me know and I mark this as a duplicate as there are 100's of answers for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), assuming all the numbers in the cells are floats:

```
import re
s = '+ 0.01 PD, OR, - 0.0005 PD, OR, - 0.001 PD'
print(re.findall('\d+\.\d+',s))
```

Output:

```
['0.01', '0.0005', '0.001']
```

---

If by chance there will also be integers, add a `'|'` to the regex string to act as an `or` operator:

```
print(re.findall('\d+\.\d+|\d+',s))
```

*Note that all the `'\d'` can also be replaced with `'[0-9]'`.*